# How to get the changed value record id in custom lookup

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have created a custom lookup based on below link:

http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/07/17/re-usable-custom-lookup/

code snippets:

```
<aura:component>
 <c:s360_customLookup objectAPIName="account" IconName="standard:account" 
selectedRecord="{!v.whatIdVal}" label="Related To" />
</aura:component>
```

In case of  custom lookup value change,I have to pass that value to another component.How to Identify changes value in Custom Lookup

---

```
  <aura:component > 
 <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.whatIdVal}" action="{!c.whatIdChanged}"/> 
<c:s360_customLookup objectAPIName="account" IconName="standard:account" selectedRecord="{!v.whatIdVal}" label="Related To"/> 
</aura:component>
```

Javscript:

```
({ 
   whatIdChanged:function(component, event, helper) { 
    alert('vall'); 
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a value change handler, the event will fire whenever the whatIdVal changes.

```
<aura:component > 
    <aura:attribute name="selectedLookUpRecord" type="sObject" default="{}"/>

    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.selectedLookUpRecord}" action="{!c.selectedLookupChanged}"/> 
    <c:s360_customLookup objectAPIName="account" IconName="standard:account" 
    selectedRecord="{!v.selectedLookUpRecord}" 
    label="Related To"/> 
</aura:component>
```

JS:

```
({ 
   selectedLookupChanged:function(component, event, helper) { 
        console.log('Selected record changed');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(component.get("v.selectedLookUpRecord")));
    } 
})
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:valueChange/documentation

Comment: I have updated the code below.alert is also not coming.I need selected record id

Comment: Can you edit your question and post it there as code snippet, its so hard to read code from comments. @AnnappaPH

Answer (score 1):

Create an application or component event for tracking the lookup change. 
Register the event in your lookup component like below
`<aura:registerEvent name="onLookupChange" type="c:LookupChangeEvent"/>` where c:LookupChangeEvent is the component or application event, **you should create it**. I prefer component event.

When the lookup value changes, the newly created events should be triggered with necessary params. Inside the lookup change handler defined under JS Controller,

```
var lookupChangeEvent = component.getEvent('onLookupChange');
lookupChangeEvent.setParams({"Id" : id}).fire();
```

The created component should be called with event handler parameter inside another component.

```
<aura:component>
    <c:s360_customLookup objectAPIName="account" IconName="standard:account" 
    selectedRecord="{!v.whatIdVal}" label="Related To" onLookupChange="{!c.lookupChangeHander}"/>
</aura:component>
```

Define the lookupChangeHander in the JS Controller to get the event params whenever the lookup changes.

```
lookupChangeHander: function(component, event, helper){
        var params = event.getParams();
        console.log(params.Id);
}
```

Please refer my blog for more details on lightning https://techevangel.com/2018/04/29/custom-lookup-component-for-lightning/

Comment: This will not work onLookupChange attribute should present in custom lookup..anyway thanks

Comment: I thought the custom component was owned by you. So I asked you to create that event handler and component event to handle the record lookup change. I have explained how it works.